# Call extension method on a potentially null property in a mapping definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

Given the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public Bar Bar {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooDetailsViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to call the following extension method in a mapping:

```
public static string ToNoneString(this string s)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return "None";
        }
        else
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the Bar property of Foo may be null, so the following doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDetailsViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Bar, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Bar.Name.ToNoneString()));
```

I know I can call the extension method in my controller after the mapping, but I was hoping I could do this somehow when I create the mapping.

Comment: Is it possible to add constructoir logic to `Foo`, to initialize it  with a default `new Bar() {ID = -1, Name = String.Empty}` so it isn't null? You'd have to validate later on of course, but this would prevent a null reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple conditional statement inside the `ForMember` call:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Bar,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(
           src => src.Bar != null ? src.Bar.Name.ToNoneString() : null));
```

You could also move the extension method up to the `Bar` class:

```
public static string ToNoneString(this Bar bar)
{
    if (bar != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bar.Name))
    {
        return bar.Name;
    }
    else 
    {
        return "None";
    }
}
```

Then update your mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Bar,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Bar.ToNoneString()));
```

Comment: Even if the Bar property is null, I want my view model's Bar property to show as "None".

Comment: @MattyM: Ah, sorry--I'll update my answer. The obvious option is to put `"None"` where `null` is in the "else" part of the conditional.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `IfNotNull` extension method:

```
static TResult IfNotNull<TSource, TResult>(
    this TSource instance,
    Func<TSource, TResult> getter,
    TResult defaultValue = default(TResult))
        where TSource : class
{
    return instance != null ? getter(instance) : defaultValue;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDetailsViewModel>()
      .ForMember(
          dest => dest.Bar,
          opts => opts.MapFrom(
                         src => src.Bar.IfNotNull(_ => _.Name).ToNoneString()));
```

`IfNotNull` is basically a primitive equivalent to C# 6 null propagation operator, which will allow you to do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDetailsViewModel>()
      .ForMember(
          dest => dest.Bar,
          opts => opts.MapFrom(
                         src => (src.Bar?.Name).ToNoneString()));
```

Comment: In C# 6, maybe you will need a parenthesis, `src => (src.Bar?.Name).ToNoneString()`. Otherwise it is my understanding that `?.` will prevent the next `.` from being "hit". I would think that was true even if that last `.` calls an extension method (not an instance method). Will someone with access to a C# 6 compiler comment, please?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, everyone has access to a C# 6 compiler, you just need to install it ;). I have an Azure VM with VS2015, I'll give it a try

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, yep, you were right... I'll fix my answer